# Crosstab function PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a question about crosstab function. I am on PostgreSQL.
So, if I use just the crosstab func itsef everything works fine. Like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab
(
'SELECT guid, selname, low
FROM source_tab
where a1  = ''RGUREP03''
order by a2, a3 asc'
)
as result_tab
(
      "b1" varchar(32), 
      "b2" varchar, 
      "b2" varchar
) ;
```

But if try to insert the result of select above into a table, I get an error:

```
insert into temp tab
(
      "b1" , 
      "b2" ,
      "b3"
)
SELECT *
FROM crosstab
(
'SELECT guid, selname, low
FROM source_tab
where a1  = ''RGUREP03''
order by a2, a3 asc'
)
as result_tab
(
      "b1" varchar(32), 
      "b2" varchar, 
      "b2" varchar
) ;
```

Text of the error:

"function cannot execute on QE slice because it access relation "source_tab"

Any help will be appretiated :)

See code above in the main part of the question.

Comment: This is an error message from GreenPlum, not from PostgreSQL. "tab" is also not a valid object in PostgreSQL.